# vs-android builds do not include gdbserver into the package

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, native

I'm trying to build an android project using vs-android and debug native code. The project builds, the .apl can be installed and it runs. However, I do not have gdbserver in /data/.../lib directory on the device.

I have debuggable attribute in the .xml, and -g specified on compiler's command line; I think I went through all the settings in the project + searched google extensively, and I am simply not seeing what I am doing wrong. Please... help?